# A problem in vector valued function

Tags: analysis, functions

Let $f:R^2 \to R^2$ be defined by $f(x,y)=(x+y,xy).$

I intend to show that inverse image of each  element in $R^2$ under f has at most two elements. that is the possibilities for the number of elements in the inverse image of each point in $R^2$ are 0,1 or 2.

I tried in the following way,

$f$ is not onto, since (2,4) does not have a preimage under $f.$

Also, i realized that no element in $R^2$ have odd number of pre images, because whenever $(x,y)$ is a pre image of an element, say $k \in $R^2$,\ \ $(y,x)$ is also a pre image of $k$ under $f.$

how to proceed further?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The other answers have pointed this out, but a particular instance might help: your statement about "no element has an odd numbers of preimages" says that "if $(x,y)$ is a preimage, so is $(y, x)$", suggesting that they come in pairs. But what if $x = y$? For instance, the preimage of $(4, 4)$ consists of a single point, $(2, 2)$.

Comment: yes, thanks, (4,4) is the only element in $R^2$ which has only one pre image under $f.$ Isn't it?

Comment: I have no idea. I just wanted to teach you that there can be a nasty catch in arguments like yours, and you have to watch out for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x,y)$ be an element of the pre-image of $(a,b)$.  Then
$$x+y=a\ ,\quad xy=b\ .$$
Using the sum-of-roots and product-of-roots formulae, this means that $x$ and $y$ are the roots of the quadratic
$$t^2-at+b\ .$$
So there are two possibilities if the quadratic has distinct real roots, one possibility if it has a double root, and no (real) possibilities if it has complex roots.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $(a,b)$ is in the image of $f$. Then you'll see that $(a,b)$ is the solution to $$
x+y=a\\
xy = b
$$ 
Note that once you find either $x$ or $y$, the other is automatically set ($x = a-y$ and $y = a-x$). So, knowing that $x = a-y$, then $xy = b$ becomes $x(a-x) = b$ which is quadratic and has at most two solutions.